Let $(X_i)_0^\infty$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables S.T. $P(X_i > 0) > 0, P(X_i = i) > 0 \forall i$, what can we we say about $E[X_i]$?
Let $(X_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent identically distributed random variables such that $P(X_i > 0) > 0 \forall i$ and $P(X_i = i) > 0  \forall i$, can we say that $\lim_{i \to \infty} E[X_i] = \infty$? Or is this indecisive?
This feels true, but if $P(x_i = i) < 1/i \forall i$ and $P(x_i > i) = 0 \forall i$ it does not seem true, because then $$E[X_i] = \sum_{i = 1}^n P(x_i = i) \leq P(x_i = i)*i < 1/i*i = 1 < \infty.$$ Then I wonder, is this even possible to have a probability distribution which satisfies $P(X_i = i) > 0 \forall i$, $P(x_i = i) < 1/i \forall i$ and $P(x_i > i) = 0 \forall i$?

If the random variables are identically distributed then $E[X_i]$ doesn’t depend on $i$. Are you sure the assumptions in your question are set up how you want them?

$X=i$ with probability $\frac  1{2^{i+1}}, n=1,2...$ and $P(X=0)=\frac  1 2$.

If $X{i}$'s are iid, then $E(X_{i})$ is a constant sequence. And no, you can let $P(X_{1}=n)=\frac{6}{\pi^{2}}\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ and still have that $E(X_{i})<\infty$  and $P(X_{i}=i)>0$ for each $i$
